# Why do I keep getting this message but the SQL syntax is working

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a problem: I keep getting this message shown below, but the add button is working (meaning it is adding data to the database).

The error below appears every time I press the `add` button. I updated the code. This is now the showlist function.

Code:

```
void Showlist()
{
    string sql = "SELECT studentnumber AS 'Student Number', lastname AS 'Last Name', firstname AS 'First Name', middlename AS 'Middle Name', picture AS 'Picture', course AS 'Course', year AS 'Year', section AS 'Section', partylist AS 'Partylist', information AS 'Information', position 'Position', election 'Election', FROM candidates";
    MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adapter.Fill(ds, "candidates");
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
    dataGridView1.DataMember = "candidates";
}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Since we have not the faintest clue about the error you are talking about (you didn't tell us), we don't know how we could help you...

Comment: Wild guess? Either `Showlist()` or `clear()` throws an exception.

Comment: You should probably change your `||` operators to `&&` if you want them all to be true (right now it says "if any of the text boxes are not empty, then do something, rather than if ALL the text boxes are not empty...)

Comment: Now I am more convinced it is `Showlist()` that is generating the error. Also, it is customary to copy the error text, not screenshot.

Comment: Given that: 1. the error message says *"...near 'FROM candidates' at line 1"*, 2. you don't have any query string shown that contains "FROM candidates", and 3. You say the database is updating correctly, then it must be in some code you aren't showing, which appears to be the call to `Showlist()`

Comment: also, your sql connection should be put in a `using` block (see [this example](https://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlconnection)), or at least put your `con.Close` in a `finally{}` block, so it happens even if there is an exception.

Comment: Please show us the Showlist() function as well.

Comment: I already posted the Showlist() function. It's too long to put here in the comment section. thank you guys :)

Comment: formatted the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an additional `,` in the select statement just before `From` .

change the sql select line as :-

```
string sql = "SELECT studentnumber AS 'Student Number', lastname AS 'Last Name', firstname AS 'First Name', middlename AS 'Middle Name', picture AS 'Picture', course AS 'Course', year AS 'Year', section AS 'Section', partylist AS 'Partylist', information AS 'Information' , position 'Position', election 'Election' FROM candidates";
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error message because of a unnecessary comma ',' before **from** keyword:

```
 ...election 'Election', FROM candidates...
```

Following is the correct version of your SQL statement:

```
 "SELECT studentnumber AS 'Student Number', lastname AS 'Last Name', firstname AS 'First Name', middlename AS 'Middle Name', picture AS 'Picture', course AS 'Course', year AS 'Year', section AS 'Section', partylist AS 'Partylist', information AS 'Information' , position 'Position', election 'Election' FROM candidates"
```

Comment: Michelle, please always share your UpVote for correct answers, if it is helful for you. Thanks